# nanoc: How can I pass options to pandoc-ruby?

Tags: ruby, pandoc, nanoc

I'm trying to use nanoc 3.5.0 with the [`pandoc`](https://github.com/nanoc/nanoc/blob/master/lib/nanoc/filters/pandoc.rb) filter that uses [`pandoc-ruby`](https://github.com/alphabetum/pandoc-ruby). Specifically, I'm not able to pass several options from my `Rules` file such that the final call to `PandocRuby.convert()` looks like this:

```
PandocRuby.convert(content,
                   {:from => :markdown, :to => :html}, :no_wrap, 
                   :table_of_contents, :mathjax, :standalone,
                   {"template" => Dir.getwd + '/layouts/pandocTemplate.html'})
```

When I place the above call in a custom filter, everything works fine. However, I would like to specify pandoc options in `Rules` such that I don't have to create a special filter for every set of options.

The default pandoc filter is defined as the function `run(content, params={})` and simply calls `PandocRuby.convert(content, params)`. How can I set `params` such that `PandocRuby.convert()` gets called correctly? The following directives in `Rules` do not work:

```
filter :pandoc, :params => { :from => :markdown, :to => :html, :no_wrap, :table_of_contents, :mathjax, :standalone, "template" => Dir.getwd + '/layouts/pandocTemplate.html' }
filter :pandoc, :params => { :from => :markdown, :to => :html, :no_wrap => true, :table_of_contents => true, :mathjax => true, :standalone => true, "template" => Dir.getwd + '/layouts/pandocTemplate.html' }
```

The first directive results in a Ruby error, the second directive runs but gives me a blank page, indicating that pandoc did not get called right. I'm not really familiar with Ruby, so my current efforts are just stabs in the dark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `pandoc` filter that comes with nanoc can’t properly do that at this point. The params given to the filter are passed through directly to `PandocRuby.convert`:

```
def run(content, params={})
  PandocRuby.convert(content, params)
end
```

([source](https://github.com/nanoc/nanoc/blob/master/lib/nanoc/filters/pandoc.rb))

Your invocation of the filter has more than two arguments, which is why it crashes. The filter certainly needs to be updated (My idea of how it could be called was too naïve). If you want to take a shot at improving the filter, you are certainly welcome to submit a pull request! I have reported this as an issue in the mean time ([link](https://github.com/nanoc/nanoc/issues/210)).

(And hopefully I can update this answer with a proper answer soon!)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! If I understand the `pandoc-ruby` documentation right, the second argument has to be the `{:from => ..., :to => ...}` hash, followed by the other options. I'll try to change the current filter but can't predict if I succeed.

Answer (score 3):

I've written a basic nanoc pandoc filter which calls pandoc directory without `pandoc-ruby`:

```
# All files in the 'lib' directory will be loaded
# before nanoc starts compiling.
# encoding: utf-8

module Nanoc::Filters

  class PandocSystem < Nanoc::Filter
    identifier :pandoc_system
    type :text => :text

    def run(content, params = {})
      if item[:extension] == 'org'
        `pandoc -f org -t html < #{item.raw_filename}`
      elsif ["md", "markdown"].index(item[:extension])
        `pandoc -f markdown -t html < #{item.raw_filename}`
      end
    end

  end

end
```

You can just pass your own options to pandoc according to `item[:extension]`. Hope it helps.

---

Update, I've create a new gist which provides an improved version of pandoc filter for nanoc, check: https://gist.github.com/xiaohanyu/9866531.

Comment: Update, this issue has been fixed by official nanoc, check: https://github.com/nanoc/nanoc/pull/433